# How to add recurring object elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I had a question, I needed optimal options to solve this problem

Problem:

```
const laptops = [{acer: 4}, {mac: 5}, {asus: 8}, {acer: 6}, {mac: 3} ];
```

output: [{acer: 10}, {mac: 8}, {asus: 8}];

the answer must be dynamic for any array

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). We encourage people to have at least attempted to work on a solution _before_ posting a question, and that code should be a [mcve].

Comment: This is not a "we code it for you" service. Please post the code you tried and what didn't work for you.